# cannot set classpath in ubuntu

Tags: java, classpath

I'm in the home directory of my Ubuntu system(18.04). There is a java class file named console lying in the directory "/Documents/java" relative to current directory. I want to run this file from my current directory by setting appropriate Classpath. I am running the program like this:

> java -cp /Documents/java console

But it says:

> Error: Could not find or load main class console

I've tried this also:

> java -cp ".:/Documents/java" console

But still getting same error.

Please correct me if I am doing it wrong and suggest the correct way. 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `/Documents/java` is not a relative path. try `./Documents/java`

Comment: Thanxx!! It is working. I just didn't know I have to include "." also.

Comment: But How would I permanently set the classpath??

Comment: You can set it in your `.bashrc` file